# Working with missing data

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
from pandas import *
from math import *
data=read_csv('agosto.csv')


      Fecha         DirViento MagViento
0 2011/07/01 00:00      N       6.6
1 2011/07/01 00:15      N       5.5
2 2011/07/01 00:30      N       6.6
3 2011/07/01 00:45      N       7.5
4 2011/07/01 01:00     ---      6.0
5 2011/07/01 01:15     ---      7.1
6 2011/07/01 01:30      S      4.7
7 2011/07/01 01:45      SE      3.1 
. 
.
.
```

The first thing i want to do, is to convert wind values ​​to numerical values ​​in order to obtain the u and v wind components. But when I perform the operations, the missing data (---) generates conflicts.

```
direccion=[]
for i in data['DirViento']:
    if i=='SSW':
     dir=202.5
    if i=='S':
     dir=180.0
    if i=='N':
     dir=360.0
    if i=='NNE':
     dir=22.5
    if i=='NE':
     dir=45.0
    if i=='ENE':
     dir=67.5
    if i=='E':
     dir=90.0
    if i=='ESE':
     dir=112.5
    if i=='SE':
     dir=135.0
    if i=='SSE':
     dir=157.5
    if i=='SW':
     dir=225.0
    if i=='WSW':
     dir=247.5
    if i=='W':
     dir=270.0
    if i=='WNW':
     dir=292.5
    if i=='NW':
     dir=315.0
    if i=='NNW':
     dir=337.5
    direccion.append(dir)
data['DirViento']=direccion
```

i get the following:

```
data['DirViento'].head()
0    67.5
1    67.5
2    67.5
3    67.5
4    67.5
```

because missing data is assigned the value of the other rows? The components of get with the following code

```
Vviento=[]
Uviento=[]
for i in range(0,len(data['MagViento'])):
    Uviento.append((data['MagViento'][i]*sin((data['DirViento'][i]+180)*(pi/180.0))))
    Vviento.append((data['MagViento'][i]*cos((data['DirViento'][i]+180)*(pi/180.0))))

data['PromeU']=Uviento
data['PromeV']=Vviento
```

Now grouped to obtain statistical data

```
index=data.set_index(['Fecha','Hora'],inplace=True)
g = index.groupby(level=0)
```

but i get error

```
IndexError: index out of range for array
```

Am I doing something wrong? How to perform operations without taking into account missing data?

Comment: If you want to add another column, which is a calculated based on the other columns, your way (looping over the rows, building a list, adding the list to the frame) is not very much in the spirit of pandas. A much better way would to go like this: `data['PromeU'] = data['MagViento']*sin((data['DirViento']+180)*(pi/180.0))`

Answer (score 1):

I see one flow in your code. You conditional statement should be more like:

```
if i == 'SSW':
    dir = 202.5
elif i == 'S':
...
else:
    dir = np.nan
```

Or you can clean `dir` variable in the beginning of the loop. Otherwise `dir` for row with missing data will be the same as `dir` for previous iteration.

But I think this code could be improved in more pythonic way, for example, something like this.

```
# test DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'DirViento':['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', '--', '--', 'S', 'SE'])

  DirViento
0         N
1         N
2         N
3         N
4        --
5        --
6         S
7        SE  

# create points of compass list
dir_lst = ['NNE','NE','ENE','E','ESE','SE','SSE','S','SSW','WSW','W','WNW','NW','NNW','N']
# create dictionary from it
dir_dict = {x: (i + 1) *22.5 for i, x in enumerate(dir_lst)}
# add a new column
df['DirViento2'] = df['DirViento'].apply(lambda x: dir_dict.get(x, None))

  DirViento  DirViento2
0         N         360
1         N         360
2         N         360
3         N         360
4        --         NaN
5        --         NaN
6         S         180
7        SE         135
```

**update** Good suggestion from @DanAllan in comments, the code becomes even shorter and even more pythonic:

```
df['DirViento2'] = df['DirViento'].replace(dir_dict)
```

Comment: Good improvement. I think ``apply(...)`` could be achieved more simply by ``replace(dir_dict)``. I haven't tested that, but I think that's how replace works.

Comment: Also, ``dir=np.nan`` instead of ``dir=None`` will allow the column datatype to be float instead of object. If he tries to use trig functions on that data, object type will throw cryptic errors.

Comment: @DanAllan thanks, have almost no time to practice pandas/python, SO is my only place for now. Changed the code. Also I'll check if replace could be modified to replace missing values to nan

Comment: I get an error when running the following code:              dir_dict = {x: (i + 1) *22.5 for i, x in enumerate(dir_lst)}
                                   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. whats the meaning 22.5?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?